# Adding Authorization Header with Camel restlet component

Tags: apache-camel, restlet, restlet-2.0

I've been using restlet camel component to communicate with endpoints fine for a couple of weeks now, but after I had the need to add an **Authorization** header to my requests, that's when I kept getting this warning:

> WARNING: Addition of the standard header "Authorization" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.

Which blocks the header from being added to the outgoing message.
I've seen solutions for this for using restlet, but I don't have the luxury when using it as a camel component.

I've tried using the `org.restlet.http.headers` attribute but still get the same message.

Any ideas how to make it send out my authorization header?
(I would rather not use the http component)

**Note:** I'm using Camel 2.19.2, same version for  restlet

Comment: What version of Camel and Restlet are you using?

Comment: Added the version I'm using to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ticket at Restlet to support this, however they have not implemented this: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1198

There is also a Camel ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10665

As it seems Restlet takes *forever* to fix this on their side, we may have to bit the bullet and make a special fix in the camel-restlet component

Comment: Thanks Claus, I guess there isn't a workaround that involves using restlet for now. I'll keep my eye on the Camel ticket (if it will get some attention)

Comment: For future reference: The issue is in https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/engine/header/HeaderUtils.java in addExtensionHeaders, where it skips adding the header if it's found in the STANRD_HEADER set

Comment: Okay I got it implemented for Authorization now, will try to get a bunch of the others implemented as well.

Comment: I can see that 2.20.0 was released, but Maven repository still doesn't have it. and I want to try out the fixes in it.

Comment: Sure it has - org.apache.camel camel-restlet 2.20.0  all (99)

Comment: Thanks Claus, the fix seems to be working for me, I've tested with Authorization and Content-Type Headers